# No function or associated item named `table` found for struct `schema::todos::table` in the current scope

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I want to create a function that uses Diesel to read all the data in postgresql and return it as a `Vec`.

## Error message

I believe this error message indicates that `todos` does not implement the `table` function. I don't think it's a problem because I have `#[derive(Queryable)]` in the model.

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `table` found for struct `schema::todos::table` in the current scope
 --> src/actions.rs:9:42
  |
9 |       let entries: Vec<TodoEntry> = todos::table.load::<TodoEntry>(&connection).expect("Error loading todos");
  |                                            ^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `schema::todos::table`
  | 
 ::: src/schema.rs:1:1
  |
1 | / table! {
2 | |     todos (id) {
3 | |         id -> Int4,
4 | |         body -> Text,
5 | |     }
6 | | }
  | |_- function or associated item `table` not found for this
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
  = note: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
          `use crate::diesel::associations::HasTable;`
```

## The relevant code

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
authors = ["hogehogehoge"]
edition = "2018"
name = "todo"
version = "0.1.0"
[dependencies]
actix-web = "3"
askama = "*"
thiserror = "*"
diesel = { version = "1.4.4", features = ["postgres", "r2d2"] }
r2d2 = "0.8"
dotenv = "0.15.0"
```

**diesel.toml**

```
[print_schema]
file = "src/schema.rs"
```

**actions.rs**

This file has a function that returns the data registered in the db as a `Vec`.

```rust
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;

use crate::models;
use crate::templates::TodoEntry;

pub fn return_all(connection: &PgConnection) -> Result<Vec<TodoEntry>, diesel::result::Error> {
    use crate::schema::todos::dsl::*;

    let entries: Vec<TodoEntry> = todos::table.load::<TodoEntry>(&connection).expect("Error loading todos");
    Ok(entries)
}
```

**templates.rs**

This file determines the data type to register in the db and then add the

```rust
#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct Todo {
    pub id: u32,
    pub text: String,
}
```

**schema.rs**

```rust
table! {
    todos (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        body -> Text,
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly suspect that your table isn't named `table`. Also, you need `#[table_name = "tablename"]` attribute on the model.

Comment: Try `todos.load(...)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you've mixed up two different ways to refer to a specific table. According to the [corresponding guide](https://diesel.rs/guides/schema-in-depth/) it's either `crate::schema::table_name::table` or `crate::schema::table_name::dsl::table_name`. You try to use `crate::schema::table_name::dsl::table_name::table`.